# get counter nested model mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

2 models:

```
Class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 has_many :reports
end

Class Report
 include Mongoid::Document
 belongs_to :user
end
```

I need a query to get all users have 6 or more reports, something like:.

```
Users.where(reports.count > 5)
```

I use mongo id 2.4.12

How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, This query is not possible since MongoDB does not have joins.

The fix for this problem is use a counter cache.

The first option is make a counter cache something like:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :reports_count, type: Integer
  has_many :reports
end

class Report
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  after_create do |doc|
    doc.user.inc(:reports_count, 1)
  end
  after_destroy do |doc|
    doc.user.inc(:reports_count, -1)
  end
end
```

The second option (I have used this option) is use this gem https://github.com/jah2488/mongoid-magic-counter-cache.

For this question:

Models:

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :report_count
 has_many :reports
end

Class Report
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::MagicCounterCache
 belongs_to :user
 end
```

Inside a helper for example:

```
def users_with_reports_greather_than_5
 users_with_reports_greather_than_5 = []
 for u in User.where(report_count.ne => nil)
  if u.report_count > 5
   users_with_reports_greather_than_5 << u
  end
 end
 return users_with_reports_greather_than_5.count
end
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
User.collection.find({"reports" => {"$size" => 5}}).count
```

to get the users who have 5 reports but to get the users who have more than 5 reports you'll have to keep an extra field (reports_count) which increments every time a new report is added. 
You can apply conditions on embedded documents as mentioned here:
( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size )

Comment: Thank you but I get `undefined method 'count' for 0:Fixnum`. I use mongo id 2.4.12. This query is working fine for me now: `User.all.select {|user| user.reports.count > 5 }` Thank you!

Comment: @hyperrjas, `User.all.select {|user| user.reports.count > 5 }` its not an correct approach. What you are doing is retrieving and loopinn all the users & reports in the database to find the report count. Check my answer for the correct way to do it mongo way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mongodb aggregation framework to find the users who got the more than 5 reports

In mongo shell

```
db.reports.aggregate(
                     // Group by user_id      
                     {$group:{_id:'$user_id',count:{$sum:1}, 

                      // Add the fields to result set along with grouped result
                      name:{$addToSet:'$any_field_you_need_to_return'}}}, 

                     // And return only the users who got greater than 5 reports
                     {$match:{count:{$gt:5}}})
```

**Update**

`Aggregate` only introduced in `moped v1.3`. You need to make a change in your gemfile to install the latest moped and run `bundle install`

```
  gem 'moped', :git=>'https://github.com/mongoid/moped.git', :branch => "master"
```

And you can use aggregate like

```
Reports.collection.aggregate(
                  {'$group' => {'_id' => '$user_id','count' => {'$sum' => 1},
                   'name' => {'$addToSet' => '$any_field_you_need_to_return'}}},
                  {'$match' => {'count' => {'$gt' => 5 }}})
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you write a query for mongoid odm? How can I add this query to my rails app? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you I get this error: `undefined method 'aggregate' for #<Mongoid::Collection:0xd8df63c>`. The model `Reports` not exists. The model is `Report`. I use mongo id 2.4.12. I need a query to get all users have 6 or more reports. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to use mongoid 3.0 or 4.0 with moped 1.3.. can you check your gem versions

Comment: `to get all users have 6 or more reports`, you need to change `{'$gt' => 5 }` this to `{'$gte' => 6 }`

Comment: Sorry but my project is mongoid 2.x.x. This response is for mongoid 3+.